# How to Block a url not a website

Tags: network

I want to block a single url. I am using `OpenDNS` now and it is working fine with website blocking on my network but the problem is that i want to block a url like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGH7NxSEGtA not http://www.youtube.com/

Is there a software which blocks a url. So that every computer connected to router cant access it.

Answer (score 5):

The mechanism by which one would would block a URL requires protocol level filtering - this is nothing at all to do with DNS or IP routing. That you mention DNS and routing in your question makes me think that you are a bit out of your depth here.

Without a grasp of the technologies, you are more likely to make your network less secure by adding stuff to it than improving it's security. I would *strongly* recommend you spend some time learning about basic network technologies.

There are lots of products available off the shelf to do URL filtering (e.g. dansguardian, websense) but for these to be of any use your network needs to be configured to force all traffic which *might* be subject to a filtering policy though it - and that means you need to know how to configure stuff like firewalls, DHCP, port translation, HTTP proxies and/or browser configuration scripts, even before considering the complications of SSL. There are multiple ways to achieve this funneling - if you ask a more specific question the you may get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 4):

To block URL, the router must work at the HTTP level; on the DNS, only server names and IP addresses are exchanged.

You need a [transparent HTTP proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy) which automatically hijacks connections, recognizes HTTP requests, and applies whatever rules it was configured with. See [this page](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/InterceptionProxy) for how to setup that with Squid (a well-known opensource HTTP proxy product).

You won't be able to filter [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) URL that way, unless you manage to subvert the *client* machines with a "rogue" CA of your own (installed in the "trust store" of each client), so that your proxy can generate on the fly fake server certificates that clients will accept as genuine (this is a [man-in-the-middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) setup). Some [commercial products](http://www.bluecoat.com/products/proxysg) do that, but, I insist, this can work only if you can inject your own CA in the client systems, which more or less means that you have sysadmin rights on all these machines.